# How to simplify the code block below with loop/array?

Tags: pine-script

this is part of the sinewave calculation and it takes 50 lines to get to "RealPart". It might be a basic question but is there any way to makes the process easier with loop or array?

```
RealPart1=iff(0<=DCPeriod-1,0+sin(DTR* 360*0/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[0]),0)
RealPart2=iff(1<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart1+sin(DTR* 360*1/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[1]),RealPart1)
RealPart3=iff(2<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart2+sin(DTR* 360*2/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[2]),RealPart2)
RealPart4=iff(3<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart3+sin(DTR* 360*3/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[3]),RealPart3)
RealPart5=iff(4<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart4+sin(DTR* 360*4/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[4]),RealPart4)
RealPart6=iff(5<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart5+sin(DTR* 360*5/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[5]),RealPart5)
RealPart7=iff(6<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart6+sin(DTR* 360*6/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[6]),RealPart6)
RealPart8=iff(7<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart7+sin(DTR* 360*7/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[7]),RealPart7)
RealPart9=iff(8<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart8+sin(DTR* 360*8/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[8]),RealPart8)
RealPart10=iff(9<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart9+sin(DTR* 360*9/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[9]),RealPart9)
RealPart11=iff(10<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart10+sin(DTR* 360*10/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[10]),RealPart10)
RealPart12=iff(11<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart11+sin(DTR* 360*11/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[11]),RealPart11)
RealPart13=iff(12<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart12+sin(DTR* 360*12/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[12]),RealPart12)
RealPart14=iff(13<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart13+sin(DTR* 360*13/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[13]),RealPart13)
RealPart15=iff(14<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart14+sin(DTR* 360*14/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[14]),RealPart14)
RealPart16=iff(15<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart15+sin(DTR* 360*15/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[15]),RealPart15)
RealPart17=iff(16<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart16+sin(DTR* 360*16/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[16]),RealPart16)
RealPart18=iff(17<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart17+sin(DTR* 360*17/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[17]),RealPart17)
RealPart19=iff(18<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart18+sin(DTR* 360*18/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[18]),RealPart18)
RealPart20=iff(19<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart19+sin(DTR* 360*19/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[19]),RealPart19)
RealPart21=iff(20<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart20+sin(DTR* 360*20/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[20]),RealPart20)
RealPart22=iff(21<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart21+sin(DTR* 360*21/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[21]),RealPart21)
RealPart23=iff(22<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart22+sin(DTR* 360*22/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[22]),RealPart22)
RealPart24=iff(23<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart23+sin(DTR* 360*23/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[23]),RealPart23)
RealPart25=iff(24<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart24+sin(DTR* 360*24/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[24]),RealPart24)
RealPart26=iff(25<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart25+sin(DTR* 360*25/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[25]),RealPart25)
RealPart27=iff(26<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart26+sin(DTR* 360*26/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[26]),RealPart26)
RealPart28=iff(27<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart27+sin(DTR* 360*27/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[27]),RealPart27)
RealPart29=iff(28<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart28+sin(DTR* 360*28/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[28]),RealPart28)
RealPart30=iff(29<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart29+sin(DTR* 360*29/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[29]),RealPart29)
RealPart31=iff(30<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart30+sin(DTR* 360*30/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[30]),RealPart30)
RealPart32=iff(31<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart31+sin(DTR* 360*31/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[31]),RealPart31)
RealPart33=iff(32<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart32+sin(DTR* 360*32/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[32]),RealPart32)
RealPart34=iff(33<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart33+sin(DTR* 360*33/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[33]),RealPart33)
RealPart35=iff(34<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart34+sin(DTR* 360*34/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[34]),RealPart34)
RealPart36=iff(35<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart35+sin(DTR* 360*35/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[35]),RealPart35)
RealPart37=iff(36<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart36+sin(DTR* 360*36/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[36]),RealPart36)
RealPart38=iff(37<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart37+sin(DTR* 360*37/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[37]),RealPart37)
RealPart39=iff(38<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart38+sin(DTR* 360*38/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[38]),RealPart38)
RealPart40=iff(39<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart39+sin(DTR* 360*39/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[39]),RealPart39)
RealPart41=iff(40<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart40+sin(DTR* 360*40/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[40]),RealPart40)
RealPart42=iff(41<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart41+sin(DTR* 360*41/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[41]),RealPart41)
RealPart43=iff(42<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart42+sin(DTR* 360*42/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[42]),RealPart42)
RealPart44=iff(43<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart43+sin(DTR* 360*43/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[43]),RealPart43)
RealPart45=iff(44<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart44+sin(DTR* 360*44/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[44]),RealPart44)
RealPart46=iff(45<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart45+sin(DTR* 360*45/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[45]),RealPart45)
RealPart47=iff(46<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart46+sin(DTR* 360*46/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[46]),RealPart46)
RealPart48=iff(47<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart47+sin(DTR* 360*47/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[47]),RealPart47)
RealPart49=iff(48<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart48+sin(DTR* 360*48/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[48]),RealPart48)
RealPart=iff(49<=DCPeriod-1,RealPart49+sin(DTR* 360*49/DCPeriod)*nz(sp[49]),RealPart49)
```

Answer (score 0):

Example with a loop.

```
var float RealPart      := 0
var float RealPart_prev := 0

for i = 0 to 49
    RealPart_prev := nz(RealPart[1])
    RealPart := i <= DCPeriod-1 ? RealPart_prev + sin(DTR*360*i/DCPeriod) * nz(sp[i]) : RealPart_prev
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, man. I tinkered around with it. The following should be the right codes.

MyRealPart(price, length) =>
    sum = price
    for i = 0 to length
        sum := sum + sin(DTR*360*i/DCPeriod) * sp[i]
    sum
plot(MyRealPart(0.0,DCPeriod-1))